# ¿Cómo copiar un empty FormData file de postman a codigo?

Tags: javascript, postman

Recientemente, estoy haciendo una aplicación móvil, pero en este caso necesito enviar un objeto de archivo vacío a la API, la API no acepta otro valor, solo archivo o objeto de archivo vacío. Enviar un archivo no es difícil

```
formData.append ('foto', {nombre: 'nombre', uri: 'uri', tipo: 'tipo'}, 'nombre_archivo')
```

pero en un caso específico necesito enviar un objeto de archivo vacío, usando postman la solicitud es similar a esto:

```
formdata.append ("foto", fileInput.files [0], "archivo");
// aquí no hay ninguna file agregada
```

Representada en postman sería así
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de esta forma el servidor contesta en forma exitosa aunque no añada ningún archivo.
abrí la consola de postman para visualizar el body request y me aparece que es del tipo undefined, no obstante si intento añadir undefined directamente la api me responde error lo que me lleva a pensar que tal vez no es del tipo undefined.

Con esto en mente me llevé la petición a la aplicación de navegador de postman para poder intentar ver por consola el tipo de dato y la sorpresa con la que me encontré es que la entrada de formulario que mostré anteriormente si la envio de la misma forma desde el navegador no funciona.

¿Alguna idea de como puedo hacer esta petición? ya intenté buscando en google el asunto es que las soluciones que me encontré muestran exactamente lo opuesto a lo que necesito acá

gracias de antemano

Comment: Podrías revisar si el encode de la petición que haces por el postman, y la que haces por código son las mismas, debería ser **multipart/form-data** para envío de archivos.

Comment: Revisé en el archivo y la codificación es la misma, de igual forma revisé en  la aplicación de escritorio de postman y en la aplicación web, son los mismos igual solo que en una si funciona el metodo y en otra no

Answer (score 0):

Al final tuve que tirar del ingenio para resolver el problema, tengo que traer la imagen del objeto que quiero actualizar y regreso un objeto de imagen con los mismos datos, el mismo nombre y el tipo de archivo solo que cambiando el uri por el de la imagen anterior